# TikTokApi and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, greenlets

I need to start the download process in the background and I use something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

api = TikTokApi()


def foo():
    url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/@karna.val/video/6912082657761381633?sender_device=mobile&sender_web_id=6919748545793050118&is_from_webapp=1'
    file = api.get_Video_By_Url(video_url=url)
    print(file)


t = Thread(target=foo)
t.start()
```

But I get the error:
`greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in your code. This removes `greenlet` error

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```